# NDSolve – Refine Spatial Mesh with TimeIntegration Method

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the following system of non-linear PDEs with 1 time  + 2 space dimensions:

```
 kp = 0.504; kt = 1.31; kd = 2.8*10^-7;

 equ1 = D[Ini[t, y, z], t] == -kd*Iabs[y, z]*Ini[t, y, z];
 equ2 = D[Rad[t, y, z], t] == 2*kd*Iabs[y, z]*Ini[t, y, z] - 2*kt*(Rad[t, y, z])^2;
 equ3 = D[DB[t, y, z], t] == -kp*Rad[t, y, z]*DB[t, y, z];
 sys = {equ1, equ2, equ3}; 
 iniconditions = {DB[0, y, z] == 12.89*10^3, Rad[0, y, z] == 0, Ini[0, y, z] == 66.2};
```

The “perturbation” `Iabs[x,y]` of the system is symmetric:

[image: Input perturbation of the system]

Here is the code to generate it:

```
wo = 5.1*10^-7; zR = 2.49*10^-6; I1 = 9.4*10^6; Eps = 387.6; zo = 200*10^-6;
w[z_] = wo*Sqrt[1 + (z/zR)^2];
Iabs[y_, z_] = I1*(wo/w[z])*Exp[(-2*y^2)/w[z]^2]*Exp[-Eps*(-z + zo)];
```

And I am therefore expecting a symmetric result.
`NDSolve` is able to provide a numeric solution to the system of equation using the `"TimeIntegration"` Method. However the resulting interpolations are asymmetric:

```
 sol = NDSolve[Join[sys, iniconditions], {DB, Rad, Ini}, {t, 0, 1}, {y, -100*wo, 100*wo}, {z, -100*10^-6, 200*10^-6}]
 DB[t_, y_, z_] = DB[t, y, z] /. sol;
 DensityPlot[(1 - DB[0.1, y, z]/(12.89*10^3))*100, {y, -100*wo,100*wo}, {z, -100*10^-6, 100*10^-6}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All,ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 100];
```

[image: Result of NDSolve]

Following this [reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86587/ndsolve-returns-asymmetric-solution-to-a-symmetric-equation) I tried to increase the number of plotted points with `PlotPoints`, it only smoothed out the result. Therefore I am also trying to refine the spatial mesh over the yz domain.

I have not found an option to do it with the `TimeIntegration` Method and using a rectangle domain to solve the system:

```
Omega = Rectangle[{-100*wo, -100*10^-6}, {100*wo, 200*10^-6}];
sol = NDSolve[Join[sys, iniconditions], {DB, Rad, Ini}, {t, 0, 1}, Element[{y,z},Omega], Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"Adams"}}]
```

Yields the following error messages

```
NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve
```

My question is then:

- Is there a way to controllably semi-discretize the problem with a more refined mesh of the yz spatial domain while maintaining the `TimeIntegration` method?

---

**Edit:**
Using `ToElementMesh` I manually defined the spatial mesh over the yz-domain and passed it to `NDSolve`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Omega = ImplicitRegion[True, {{y, -100*wo, 100*wo}, {z,-100*10^-6, 200*10^-6}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Omega, MaxCellMeasure -> wo/10 000];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

With `MaxCellMeasure -> wo/10 000`, the mesh is a bit coarse but I also tried with `MaxCellMeasure-> wo/100 000` unsuccessfully:

When I pass this mesh to NDSolve, I obtain the same error message as when using `ImplicitRegion`

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[sys, iniconditions], {DB, Rad, Ini}, {t, 0, 1}, Element[{y, z}, mesh], Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"Adams"}}];
NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve. >>
```

So I don't understand why `NDSolve` is able to solve the system by itself using the `TimeIntegration` Method but whenever I try to improve the mesh quality it doesn't work.

Comment: Something is going wrong with the brackets, did you mean `I1*(wo/w[z])*Exp[(-2*y^2)/w[z]^2] Exp[-Eps*(-z + zo)]`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: What code do you actually use to generate the (asymmetric) plot? The `NDSolve[]` generates three 3D `InterpolationFunction`s

Comment: Please chek the edited code above the picture of the solution

Comment: Have you seen [`ToElementMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) and the related FEM tutorials?

Comment: @MichaelE2, Please check the edits. `ToElementMesh` gives the same error as `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: Have you seen the `"SpatialDiscretization"` option of the Method of Lines?

Comment: It works well with the `TensorGrid`option. Thank you very much @MichaelE2 !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelE2's comment, I tried the following:

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[sys, iniconditions], {DB, Rad, Ini}, {t, 0, 1}, {y,-100*wo, 100*wo}, {z, -100*10^-6, 200*10^-6},Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" ->{"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 400}}}]
```

Which gives a correct symmetric solution to the system of PDEs:

```
DB[t_, y_, z_] = DB[t, y, z] /. sol;
DensityPlot[(1 - DB[0.3, y, z]/(12.89*10^3))*100, {y, -40*wo,40*wo}, {z,-74*10^-6, 74*10^-6}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Correct symmetric solution]

The trick was here to put `"MinPoints"` to at least 200 otherwise `NDSolve` was returning:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`. >>
```